# PDO insert error: OCIStmtExecute: ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: php, sql, oracle10g, pdo, object-relational-model

I have a PDO insert problem. Here is my code snippet. It binds the data value (submitted by user) to the data params;

```
    ...
    if((is_int($actualVal)) || ($actualVal ==NULL)){
    print $actualVal .' is INT<br>';
    $objStatement->bindValue(':'. $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

    else {
        print $actualVal .' is STR<br>';
        $objStatement->bindValue(':'. $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    };
```

For  instance when I provide the following data values:

```
$objRental->setRentalFacultyId('29');
$objRental->setRentalResCenterId(17);
$objRental->setRentalPurpose("purpose");
$objRental->setRentalDateReturned("2011-10-01");
$objRental->setRentalDateRented("2008-01-05");
$objRental->setRentalDateSaved("2001-12-12");
$objRental->setRentalUserIdSaved('3');
$objRental->setRentalReturnStatus('Y');
$objRental->setRentalSupervisorId('5');
```

I get the results and error as:
results:

```
int 23
23 is INT
string 'purpose' (length=7)
purpose is STR
int 17
17 is INT
int 29
29 is INT
string '2008-01-05' (length=10)
2008-01-05 is STR
string '2011-10-01' (length=10)
2011-10-01 is STR
string '2001-12-12' (length=10)
2001-12-12 is STR
int 5
5 is STR
int 3
3 is STR
string 'Y' (length=1)
Y is STR
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 12899 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-12899: value too large for column "....." (actual: 19, maximum: 15) (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:146)

The problem seems to occur I think because PDO is changing that data length of my data value. How can I solve this?

Comment: my datatype lengths in DB actually look like this, so I dont think I am wrongly providing values exceeding the datalength even though that is the error shown. datatype lengths:   
FACILITY_ID Varchar2 60  
RENTAL_RC_ID Varchar2 60  
RENTAL_DATE_RENT Timestamp(6)
RENTAL_DATE_RTURN Timestamp(6)
RENTAL_SUPVSOR Varchar2 15 
RENTAL_DATE_S Timestamp(6)
RENTAL_STAFF_ID_S Varchar2 15 
RENTAL_DATE_E Timestamp(6)
RENTAL_STAFF_ID_E Varchar2 15 
RENTAL_VENUE Varchar2 100 
RENTAL_RTURN_STATUS Varchar2 1 
RENTAL_PURPOSE Varchar2 200 
RENTAL_FACULTY_ID Varchar2 15 
RENTAL_DATEDUE_RTURN, Timestamp(6)

Answer (score 1):

Your table has this:

```
RENTAL_FACULTY_ID Varchar2 15
```

And your PHP has this:

```
$objRental->setRentalFacultyId('29');
```

But then we see this:

```
29 is INT
```

So the rental_faculty_id needs to be a string when it gets to the database but someone is converting it to an integer because `'29'` looks like an integer; that someone is most likely the `if` condition in this:

```
if((is_int($actualVal)) || ($actualVal ==NULL)){
    print $actualVal .' is INT<br>';
    $objStatement->bindValue(':'. $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
else {
    print $actualVal .' is STR<br>';
    $objStatement->bindValue(':'. $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

If you try to bind a number for something that expects a string, you'll get odd behavior.

You should be using the database schema — not the incoming data — to determine if you should bind with `PDO::PARAM_INT` or `PDO::PARAM_STR`. The [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) function should be returning false for `'29'` so maybe something is trying to be "clever" between the `setRentalFacultyId` call and the above `if` statement.